# Error with dependance @types/geojson

Tags: reactjs, typescript, geojson

I'm using react.js , with typescript and webpack configuration.

I've a problem with the dependency @types/geojson
When I compil my app , I have errors in my console

```
error TS1005 , expected
type parameter name cannot be any
```

I have the version 1.0.6 of @types/geojon, and the version 0.0.5 of geojson.

My npm version is 3.10.8

Do you have an idea about this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, download the typescript version 2.3.0, and it would be work